# Android Read and Write File to Serial Port at Specific Frequency

Tags: android, file, text

Greetings. I have been using Serial PORT API to Transmit Data to Serial Port and the following code to read and write file to serial port.

```
File file = new File(musicpath + "file.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line="";
        int c,counter=0;
        while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
            String s = new StringBuilder().append("").append((char)c).toString();
            MainActivity.sendDataChar(s);

        }


    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
```

I have been transmitting 8 BIT MONO WAVE FILES  @ 22Khz from SD CARD using RS485 and I do have hardware to playback the transmitted data using DAC. (BOTH TRANSMITTER and RECEIVER uses ARM7 - LPC2148).

Now my idea is to have the 8 BIT WAVE FILE stored in SDCARD of Android Device and transmit the same at specified frequency using timer.

I wanted to know how to do this. I tried the above method but I do understand that the transmission frequency does not match as I needed. (PORT OPENED AT 230400 baud rate).

With the above code, a 155 KB File should take approximately 6-7 seconds to finish up the transmission character by character. But it really takes about 15-20 seconds and I dont have the audio output at the receiver end. Just the noise.

Kindly advise me and give some ideas on how to do it in realtime just like the way I managed to do it in ARM7.

Thanks a Lot